# How to retrieve a Java object attribute (with Spring MVC) in Polymer web-components

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to build some web pages in JSP (framework Spring MVC 4) using Polymer 1.0.

I would like to see some values from the Java object "User" in the web page but I can't understand how can I do to retrieve these values on Polymer.

First, I set a new object User in the Spring Controller and the method test() will retrieve a ModelAndView object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView test() {
        logger.info("-- Method: test()");

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstname("fname");

        ModelAndView data  = new ModelAndView();
        data.addObject("user", user);
        data.setViewName("test");

        return data;
    }
```

After this, I put the ModelAndView object in my custom element in Polymer:

```
...
<custom-element userdata="${user}"></custom-element>
...
```

Finally, I create my "custom-element" using Polymer library:

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">

    <template>
        <span>{{userdata.firstname}}</span>
    </template>

    <script>
    Polymer({

        is: "custom-element",
        properties: 
        {
            userdata: 
            {
                type: Object
            }
        }});
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

When I launch the webpage, I can't see the value "fname" in the page...why? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i don't see any binding issue in your code with polymer .

if your jsp is showing null for the {{user.firstname}} implies that there should be an error in request mapping in the controller. As a result this method test is never called to set the Firstname variable of the user model.

make sure the mapping is done properly in MVC

Comment: thanks for reply! I checked your question and I can confirm that the method test is invoked correctly...I'm loosing my mind